# include_once many files at once. does it will cause any problem?

Tags: php, include

I come across an application using this method to include all class files by using this code

```
   foreach(glob("class/*.php") as $file)
     {
      include_once "$file";
     }
```

It actually works, but do not know this way to include all files at once would cause any problems later? Is this method to include many files at once recommended?

Thanks

Comment: maybe using require once will be a better option

Answer (score 4):

I think autoloading would be better.

Check out here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

One simple example from the document could be tweaked to suit your case

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include 'class/'. $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create a lot of unnecessary overhead if any of the classes aren't used. Each file will have to be parsed which will be unnecessarily time consuming. I agree with @Liangliang Zheng 100% in that you should use `__autoload`. As for the suggestion of @lbu and your original solution, it is recommended to not use the **_once** versions, they are more costly than just using `include` and `require`.